# Is there any way to get Bindings to update with properties of a "simple" object (e.g. a DTO that lacks IPropertyChanged code)?

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm working on a MAUI project and would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or this simplay isn't possible. I have a simple object with some properties that I bind to the Text property of Entry elements in my XAML using two way binding. The data gets displayed correctly, but it doesn't update when I type into the field. I didn't write the OnPropertyChanged myself as I use the MVVM toolkit, so I'm guessing that could be the problem. Does anyone have any more knowledge on this?
The class:

```
public class RegisterDTO
{
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Nejm";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    public string Country { get; set; } = "";
    public string City { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } = null;
}
```

The view model utilizing it:

```
public partial class RegisterPageVM : BaseVM
{
    public RegisterPageVM() {
        Title = "Register";
        dto = new RegisterDTO();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private RegisterDTO dto;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your problem is that you're using the DTO directly in the ViewModel and the properties of the DTO are not *observable*, they don't raise `PropertyChanged` events. This also means, they're not usable for bindings other than `OneTime`. Bindings generally require the properties to raise `PropertyChanged` events, not the parent object.

Comment: That's what I thought yeah. Is there any way of using such DTOs in a ViewModel without having to write each property in the VM separately, or is this the only option?

Comment: Yes, you could technically put `[ObservableProperty]` in front of each field, change them all to lower case and remove the getters and setters, like so: `[ObservableProperty] string email;` and so on. Your DTO needs to inherit from `ObservableObject` then. I don't think it's good design, though.

Comment: Fody PropertyChanged is a nuget package that will inject PropertyChanged into your models.  It’s magical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work-around is to declare "proxy" properties in your VM, that manipulate the DTO (simple object) properties:

```cs
// Syntax below assumes VM inherits from `ObservableObject`.
// In question code, that means `BaseVM` inherits from `ObservableObject`.
public string Email {
  get => dto.Email;
  set => SetProperty(dto.Email, value, dto, (d, v) => d.Email = v);
}
```

See code snippet in [ObservableObject / Wrapping a non-observable model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#wrapping-a-non-observable-model) for explanation of that `SetProperty` syntax.

- Change XAML to use these new properties:
  `{Binding Email}`, rather than `{Binding Dto.Email}`.