# Child property of an ObservableProperty is not updating

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

Something isn't right with the XAML but it's not sticking out at me.

I've been working on the layout of one of my .net Maui XAML pages.  I added a collectionView when I noticed that the top data was no longer showing.  The other pages are working fine.

What's weird is that the data is there and while running the app in debug mode if I highlight, shift-delete, then paste it back in the bound data appears.  I also noticed if I change the {Binding EditEvent.name} by removing the "name" from EditEvent then adding it back on, the view displays the data as well.

But if I leave and navigate back in the data won't show up until I repeat the above process.  It's like the viewModel isn't updating the view when the data changes.  But if I force the view to update by deleting and re-pasting it will show it.

Anyone have an idea what possibly could be the issue?

I've got 2 ObservableProperties in my ViewModel:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SharedModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
public partial class EditEventViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region XAML page Observables
    [ObservableProperty]
    attEventDx editEvent;

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<groupReturn> groupsItems;
    #endregion

    // pass object to edit into this view
    public async void SetEditEvent(attEventDx incomingEvent)
    {
        editEvent = incomingEvent;

        //await LoadGroupsAsync();
        
    }
...
}
```

And this is the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Pages.EditEventPage"
         Title="Edit Event"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
         xmlns:dm="clr-namespace:SharedModels;assembly=SharedModels"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:EditEventViewModel"
         NavigatedTo="ContentPage_NavigatedTo">

<VerticalStackLayout>


    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="0,40,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Event Name"  VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding EditEvent.name}" WidthRequest="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Label Text="Event Date"  VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding EditEvent.happeningOn}" WidthRequest="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>


    </Grid>

    <Label Text="Selectable Groupings" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Padding="20"/>

    <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsItems}" SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="dm:groupReturn">
                <SwipeView>
                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                    </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <Grid Padding="0,5">
                        <Label Text="Groups"/>
                        <ScrollView>
                            <Frame>
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:EditEventViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label Text="{Binding groupName}" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </Grid>

                </SwipeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

this is my xaml.cs for that page:

```
public partial class EditEventPage : ContentPage, IQueryAttributable
{
EditEventViewModel _vm;

attEventDx _editEvent;

public EditEventPage( EditEventViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _vm = vm;
    BindingContext = _vm;
}

public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
{
    _editEvent = query["EditEvent"] as attEventDx;

}

private void ContentPage_NavigatedTo(object sender, NavigatedToEventArgs e)
{
    _vm.SetEditEvent(_editEvent);
}
}
```

attEventDx for reference (sits in another shared project between Azure Functions and the mobile app):

```
namespace SharedModels
{
    public class attEventDx
    {
        public Guid? publicId { get; set; }
        public int? createdBy { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? happeningOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As I referred to this is the page that IS working:

xaml.cs:

```
public partial class EventPage : ContentPage
{
EventViewModel _vm;

public EventPage(EventViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _vm = vm;
    BindingContext= _vm;
}

private async void ContentPage_NavigatedTo(object sender, NavigatedToEventArgs e)
{
    await _vm.LoadEventData();
}

private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class EventViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region XAML page Observables

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<attEventDx> eventItems;

    [ObservableProperty]
    attEventDx selectedEvent;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string text;

    #endregion

    public EventViewModel()
    {
        //EventItems = new ObservableCollection<attEventDx>();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task LoadEventData()
    {
        MyApp.globals.SetHttpClient();

        try
        {
            var response = await MyApp.globals.httpClient.GetAsync(MyApp.globals.APIURL + "getEvents");
            var allEvents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (allEvents != null)
            {
                List<attEventDx> listOfEvents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<attEventDx>>(allEvents);

                if (listOfEvents != null)
                {
                    EventItems = new ObservableCollection<attEventDx>(listOfEvents);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\r\b" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Add()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(AddEventPage)}");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap(attEventDx sender)
    {
        selectedEvent = sender;

        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["EditEvent"] = selectedEvent
        };

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EditEventPage)}", navigationParameter);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Refresh()
    {
        await LoadEventData();
    }
}
```

And the view of the working page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.EventPage"
         Title="Events"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
         xmlns:dm="clr-namespace:SharedModels;assembly=SharedModels"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:EventViewModel"
         NavigatedTo="ContentPage_NavigatedTo">


<Grid RowDefinitions="100, Auto, 30, *"
      ColumnDefinitions=".50*, .25*, .25*"
      Padding="10">

    <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
           Source="logo.png"
           BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>

    <ImageButton Source="plus.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Scale=".7" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"></ImageButton>
    <Label Text="New Event" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"></Label>
    <!--<Entry Placeholder="Enter Text" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}" />-->
    <!--<Button Text="Search" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />-->
    <!--<Button Text="Add" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>-->

    <Label Text="Upcoming Events" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <!--<Button Text="Refresh" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/>-->
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding EventItems}" SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="dm:attEventDx">
                <SwipeView>
                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                    </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <Grid Padding="0,5">
                        <Label Text="Event"/>
                        <ScrollView>
                            <Frame>
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:EventViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <Label Text="{Binding happeningOn}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0,0,5,0"></Label>
                    </Grid>

                </SwipeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: is `attEventDx` Observable?

Comment: Yes, it's listed in the above code as ObservableProperty... Actually attEventDx is the type, the EditEvent is the [ObservableProperty].

Comment: it doesn't matter if `EditEvent` is observable, you are binding to a property on `attEventDx`, so that class/property needs to be Observable

Comment: attEventDx is a datatype, it doesn't contain data...? It's an object that exists in another project shared by the Azure Functions and the .net Maui App.  This same pattern is used on multple functioning pages...?

Comment: what the heck is a "datatype that doesn't contain data"?  It's a C# class with properties.  Just because it's defined in another project doesn't change that.  If you want the UI to dynamically update when a property on ClassX changes, ClassX needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  That's how binding works.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying.  This exact object is used in the page prior to this one and it's working fine...  The object I'm referencing on the view is "editEvent", not attEventDx.  My understanding that adding the [ObservableProperty] adds the INotifyPropertyChanged  on the variable.  I have the shared object in the question for your review.

Comment: You are specifically talking about `EditEvent.name` where `name` is a property on the class `attEventDx`.  Adding `ObservableProperty` to `EditEvent` makes `EditEvent` observable - it does not recursively apply to child properties.  I can only make comments on the code the you posted, so I have no idea what is going on in some other page.

Comment: This is what I am using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty  It creates the INotifyPropertyChanged automatically on all child properties.

Comment: There is nothing in those docs that mentions child properties.  You can easily test this by seeing if `OnPropertyChanged` fires when you update the `name` property

Comment: [Now that the code is shown.] While `name` is indeed a property, it **does not** include `OnPropertyChanged` logic. You'll have to fix that. An alternative fix is [a proxy property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75045132/199364). In your case, define a `name` property, that refers to `EditEvent.name`. (You can name this new property whatever you like; be sure to change xaml to refer to it.)

Comment: This is so odd... I'm not doing any of that in this app or in another that I wrote and I'm able to call child properties with the community toolkit.  And the only page that isn't working is this one.  This is a "details" page to the parent CollectionView which is bound to an [ObservableProperty][ObservableCollection] of type attEventDx.

Comment: Right. Properties (and sub-properties) are correctly read at the time BindingContext is set; no PropertyChanged notification required. The problem occurs if you make any change AFTER BindingContext is set. Then there is no notification. There is a hack you can do: `var hold = BindingContext; BindingContext = null; BindingContext = hold;`. This re-reads all bindings.

Comment: I just put up the working page to show one that is working.  Going to look at the suggested page, but I think I already read that one.

Comment: Ah got it, I understand now what you are saying about the BindingContext.  I was setting the binding context while the variables were "null" in the page.  I moved the BindingContext to past the load and it's working a-ok now.  However, on the parent page I am setting the BindingContext prior to loading data... I'll have to look at that again when I have more time.  But for now, it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what ToolmakerSteve told me kind of worked, the items were initially displaying but not updating.

I then decided to build out another page in the app and do some experimenting along the way and figured out the issue.

When I created the new page by hand, I still had this issue and was doubting my sanity.  I then partially copied in the page that was working and it worked!  In comparing the two pages closely, I finally discovered what the problem was.

I was right, the CommunityToolkit's [ObservableProprerty] DOES work for all child items in an object; this is why I selected using this library from the start.  I wasn't going crazy... (At least not on this)

This particular app was started a few months ago but then I got pulled into another project in another platform for a few months so what I had learned was partially forgotten when I picked it back up recently.

When you define a [ObservableProperty] like this:

```
[ObservableProperty]
myObject usedVariable;
```

The "usedVariable" will contain the data, but not the framework for INotifyPropertyChanged.  CommunityToolkit builds out the framework on "UsedVariable".

While this code is "legal" in the ViewModel:

```
usedVariable = new myObject();
```

It will assign the data, but not the notification framework.

Instead it needs to be:

```
UsedVariable = new myObject();
```

Once the variable is defined with lowercase, you will never reference the variable that way again (as far as I can tell anyway).  Instead, you will use the uppercase "UsedVariable".

When I referenced the lowercase version of the variable, I didn't see the data on the app page when it started.  However, if I had the page open and I removed the XAML code for that control and pasted it back in, the data did show.

It's always something simple that causes the most grief...

Comment: FWIW: *"the CommunityToolkit's [ObservableProprerty] DOES work for all child items in an object"* I don't think that is true. This can be tested by doing `MyProperty.MySubProperty = ...;` AFTER the page has loaded. AFAIK, it CANNOT update what is displayed. (Technically, the top property has no way to know its chid property has changed.) Nested properties work fine when a page is first loaded (the top property doesn't even have to be Observable. It does have to have a get/set, which ObservableProperty is one way to define). It also works fine if you change the main property.

Comment: ... of course if the child property itself is ObservableProperty or child property's setter does OnPropertyChanged, that will work. My point is that the child property is the only one who knows when it changes, so it is the only one who can tell xaml about a change. This is fundamental to C#.

Comment: It works great for me @ToolmakerSteve.  Since I figured this out, I've wired up all the rest of the objects using it.  There's several requirements to make that work in code though.  I've got complex objects coming back and displaying correctly now on the page using only the community toolkit and the above code (with the change in the capital letter at the start of the variable)